# Selenium Python Error httplib.BadStatusLine: '' when loading new URL (Firefox)

Tags: python, selenium, http, firefox

I'm using Selenium with Python and Firefox and when I load a new website, e.g.

```
driver.get("http://www.apple.com")
time.sleep(5)
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
time.sleep(5)
```

I get the following error:

```
httplib.BadStatusLine: ''
```

I found this following possible solution, but it doesn't help (still crashes, but no error message anymore)

```
except httplib.BadStatusLine:
        pass
```

Comment: I'm using firefox and the newest version, so a chrome update (which fixed the issue in the stated question) won't help

Comment: You have the current version of `geckodriver` and `selenium` as well?

Comment: Yes, also `geckodriver` and `selenium` are up-to-date. However, I've now tried Google Chrome and there everything works - this workaround solved the issue for me